# I'm trying to use stringr, specifically regex, to cut up "MA: Bristol County (25005)"

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to take a variable column and cut it up into several columns. The values follow a basic pattern with the county name having a variety of lengths and formats.

```
State-county :
[1] "MA: Bristol County (25005)"
[2] "LA: St. Tammany Parish (22103)"
[3] "CA: Ventura County (06111)"    
[4] "CA: San Mateo County (06081)"
```

I need a state, county name, and county code column that I can add back into the data.frame. Been trying to figure out how to use str_extract to accomplish the task.
Ideally, this is where I'd end up, but I'll take any help I can get.

```
  state:    county:            county code: 
[1] "MA"   Bristol County       25005
[2] "LA"   St. Tammany Parish   22103
[3] "CA"   Ventura County       06111    
[4] "CA:   San Mateo County     06081
```

I was able to use this code I found `str_extract_all( "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))")` for the county code (thanks [Nettle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4647310/nettle)) and the closest I could get to the state abrev was
`'str_extract_all( h,"..:")`
which is close but includes the ":"
also tried: `str_extract_all( "(?<=\\:")`

Sorry if this isn't the best format, I tried to be really clear and in the style I've seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str_match_all`:

```r
str_match_all(df$State_county, "([A-Z]+): ([^()]+) \\((\\d+)\\)")

as_tibble(df) %>%
 mutate(matches=str_match_all(State_county, "([A-Z]+): ([^()]+) \\((\\d+)\\)")) %>%
  unnest_wider(matches) %>%
   select(-2) %>%
    set_names("State_county", "State", "County", "ZIP")
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  State_county                   State County             ZIP  
  <fct>                          <chr> <chr>              <chr>
1 MA: Bristol County (25005)     MA    Bristol County     25005
2 LA: St. Tammany Parish (22103) LA    St. Tammany Parish 22103
3 CA: Ventura County (06111)     CA    Ventura County     06111
4 CA: San Mateo County (06081)   CA    San Mateo County   06081

### OR with str_match as we're only using a single pattern
## this saves us from the warning caused by unnest_wider
as_tibble(df)  %>%
 mutate(matches=str_match(State_county, "([A-Z]+): ([^()]+) \\((\\d+)\\)"), State=matches[,2], County=matches[,3], ZIP=matches[,4], matches=NULL)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  State_county                   State County             ZIP  
  <fct>                          <chr> <chr>              <chr>
1 MA: Bristol County (25005)     MA    Bristol County     25005
2 LA: St. Tammany Parish (22103) LA    St. Tammany Parish 22103
3 CA: Ventura County (06111)     CA    Ventura County     06111
4 CA: San Mateo County (06081)   CA    San Mateo County   06081 
### Another way 
str_match(df$State_county, "([A-Z]+): ([^()]+) \\((\\d+)\\)") %>%
 as.data.frame %>% set_names("State_county", "State", "County", "County_code")
                    State_county State             County County_code
1     MA: Bristol County (25005)    MA     Bristol County       25005
2 LA: St. Tammany Parish (22103)    LA St. Tammany Parish       22103
3     CA: Ventura County (06111)    CA     Ventura County       06111
4   CA: San Mateo County (06081)    CA   San Mateo County       06081
```

#### Explanation:

`str_match` will basically return the captured groups (sub patterns written in non escaped parenthesis `([A-Z]+)`) and the full string that matched the full pattern

- `[A-Z]+` : matches the state abrv.
- `[^()]+` : matches anything that's not an opening parenthesis. the county.
- `\\((\\d+)\\)` : matches the open parenthesis `\\(` and closing one while it pulls the digits using grouping. the county code.

```r
str_match(df$State_county, "([A-Z]+): ([^()]+) \\((\\d+)\\)")
     [,1]                             [,2] [,3]                 [,4]   
[1,] "MA: Bristol County (25005)"     "MA" "Bristol County"     "25005"
[2,] "LA: St. Tammany Parish (22103)" "LA" "St. Tammany Parish" "22103"
[3,] "CA: Ventura County (06111)"     "CA" "Ventura County"     "06111"
[4,] "CA: San Mateo County (06081)"   "CA" "San Mateo County"   "06081"
```

Comment: this is so comprehensive and amazing thanks!! I have such a hard time unpcking and remembering the regex so I super appreciate you explaining it a bit. 

The closing parathenses on `(\\d+)` in `\\((\\d+)\\)` are necessary to indicate what characters I want (in this case chr between `\\(` and `\\)`  )?

can you elaborate on how this: `([^()]+)` works? enclosing parentheses are to separate it from the other expressions?
 ` [^()]+ `  -> `^(` indicates chr before the "(" and the "+" is for "1 or more chr"? 
what does the rest do( i.e. brackets and ")"  ?

Comment: @JasonDeutsch u only need `[^(]` (the closing parenthesis is a typo :)) means match any character that's not a parenthesis one or more times, Note that we don't escape it due to the fact that it's in a character class. For your first question in regex parenthesis are special they define what characters you want to keep so in order to match a parenthesis u can either escape them `\(` (in R you need to double escape) or put them in a character class `[(]`  so `\\((\\d+)\\)` <=> `[(](\\d+)[)]`; `\d+` matches one digit or more.

Comment: thanks again!

\n  one more followup :
\n   " [^(]  means match any character that's not a parenthesis one or more times "
why doesn't that then capture the state abbreviation or the numbers after? 
Is the state abrv already gone b/c of the first regex? And we're then only selecting characters not "(" ?         \n I thought the ^ indicated that we're selecting characters that come before the "("  in the "^("

Comment: @JasonDeutsch ok ^ outside of a character class means beginning of string. the state abbrv was already matched by [A-Z]+ and [^(]+ stops when it finds the opening parenthesis i.e it'll match `Bristol County`

Comment: could you help with an additional issue I'm having? have a string ".De Baca County, New Mexico" and I'm trying to just get the county name and strip out the "County, New Mexico" the code I'm using so far is >>>]> population_data[[2]] <- population_data[[2]] %>% 
+     str_remove("\\.") %>%
+     str_remove( "County") %>%
+     str_remove( "(,) ([^ ]+)([^ ]+)")  ## alternatively str_replace( "([^,]+), (\\w+)", "\\1 ")

Comment: `([A-Z]+): ([^()]+) (?:County, .+? )?\\((\\d+)\\)` will work @JasonDeutsch

Comment: I think you're thinking of my original question, this is a similar but different dataset. The data is:: ".De Baca County, New Mexico" as opposed to "MA: Bristol County (25005)" with the desired output being "De Baca"  after stripping "County" and anything to the right of "County" . #### the tricky bit is the data base includes all states and "County" is not always present but the "," is

Comment: `([A-Za-z ]+?) (?:County)?,? ([A-Za-z ]+?)` I guess you want to extract the county name and state the regex above will do this, if you can provide the case where county isn't included I can help make it more precise

Comment: c<-c(".De Baca County, New Mexico",".Bernalillo County,
     New Mexico",".Guadalupe County, New Mexico",
     ".Big Horn County, Wyoming",
     "Ketchikan Gateway Borough, Alaska",
     ".Cattaraugus County, New York") ##### looking for output ### c<-c("De Baca","Bernalillo","Guadalupe",
     "Big Horn",
     "Ketchikan Gateway Borough",
     "Cattaraugus")

Comment: `str_extract(vec, "([A-Za-z ]+?)(?= County|,)")` this would work sorry for the late response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225650/discussion-between-jason-deutsch-and-abdessabour-mtk).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidyr`'s `extract` to get data into different columns specifying the regex that you want to use the divide the data.

```
tidyr::extract(df, col, 
               c('state', 'county', 'county_code'), 
               '(\\w+):\\s*(.*)\\((\\d+)\\)')

#  state             county  county_code
#1    MA     Bristol County        25005
#2    LA St. Tammany Parish        22103
#3    CA     Ventura County        06111
#4    CA   San Mateo County        06081
```

We use 3 capture groups to extract the data from `col` column.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(col = c("MA: Bristol County (25005)", 
                "LA: St. Tammany Parish (22103)", 
"CA: Ventura County (06111)", "CA: San Mateo County (06081)")), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an entirely base R approach, which uses `strsplit` to separate the three components:

```r
output <- apply(df, 1, function(x) { strsplit(x, "(?:: | \\(|\\))")})
output <- unlist(output, recursive=FALSE)
names(output) <- c(1:length(output))
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, output))
names(df) <- c("state", "county", "zip")
df

  state             county   zip
1    MA     Bristol County 25005
2    LA St. Tammany Parish 22103
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(state=c("MA: Bristol County (25005)",
                         "LA: St. Tammany Parish (22103)"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response!  can you explain the first two lines of code? are you creating a function?

Comment: The first two lines of code basically split the input at colon and also before the zip code.  The rest of the code generates the data frame you want.